# For regular language a*b*, is there a superset of it which is non-regular?

Tags: regular-language, computation-theory

Language `A = a*b*` is absolutely a regular language.
But I am wondering if there is a superset of it is non-regular language? And the superset must use the same alphabet {a,b}

Comment: Why shouldn't there be? A union of a regular language `A` with any non-regular language `B` is both a superset of `A` and non-regular.

Comment: ...at least if they have disjoint alphabets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. Take B=b<sup>n</sup>ab<sup>n</sup> (where n>0), that is the language of palindromes that start with `b` and contain a single `a` in the middle. This language is non-regular because the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) doesn't apply to it. It is also completely disjoint with `A` because every word in `B` contains the `ba` substring, while none of the words in `A` do.

A union of `A` and `B` is therefore a non-regular superset of `A`.

It is also easy to prove that not all regular languages can be extended this way because for example the language of every possible word over a given alphabet is by definition regular. Since there is no way to formulate a non-trivial superset of this language over the same alphabet, all supersets of the "Kleene star" language over a given alphabet will also be regular.

More generally, any language A whose complement language (C<sub>A</sub>=Σ<sup>*</sup>\A) is finite won't have a non-regular superset, because C<sub>A</sub> and all its subsets are by definition regular *(finite languages are always regular)*, and therefore the union of any of them with A is also regular *(the union of two regular languages is regular)*.